# How to increase max-height but from bottom to top?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this:

```
<div id = "parent">
    <div id = "button"></div>
</div>
```

and a `<div id="list"></div>` who is dynamically generated
i can do this

```
$("#button").on("clicked",function(){   
    $("#parent").append(list)
    $("#parent").animate({ "max-height": '300px' }, 500)
}
```

to show my list div from button's bottom ，and animating like drop from top to bottom
and now i need some negative way which means like:

```
$("#button").on("clicked",function(){  
    $("#parent").prepend(list)
    $("#parent").animate({ "max-height": '300px' }, 500)
}
```

but this↑ is not perfect when the height getting bigger the div will still drop down but not rise up

how can i make the parent div's height rising up? thanks to any responses

Comment: Please show us slightly more complete code, include relevant CSS. Do you have the div positioned at the bottom for example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I solved this stupid question by bottom:0
so its belike this: if you have

```
<div id="big_div">
    <div id="small_div"></div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
#big_div{
   position:relative;
}
#small_div{
   position:absoulute;
   bottom:0px;
   height:0px;
}
```

when you`$("#small_div").animate({"height":"100px"})`
the child div would grow up from bottom to top, it's because the small_div is positioned by bottom so when its height getting bigger it would only can rise up

in my question, the big_div is the container,the small_div is the parent_div, i limit parent_div:`max-height:20px` which is as big as my button_div, and everytime i use : `$("#parent_div").append(list_div)` `$("#parent_div").prepend(list_div)` or  to get my dynamically generated lists

and then, when i need list_div expand drop，i use:

```
$("#parent_div").css({
    "bottom":"auto",
    "top":the_position_i_need_top,
    "max-height":button_height+list_height
})
$("#button_div").css("top","0px")
$("#parent_div").append(list_div)
$("#list_div").animate({"height",list_height},1000)
```

when i want my list rise up from button'top:

```
$("#parent_div").css({
    "bottom":the_position_i_need_but_bottom,
    "top":"auto",
    "max-height":button_height+list_height
})
$("#button_div").css("bottom","0px")
$("#parent_div").prepend(list_div)
$("#list_div").animate({"height",list_height},1000)
```

the css is like:

```
#parent{
    width:100px;
    max-height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#package_use_targetsContainer{
    height:0px;
}

#package_use_top{
    position:relative;
}
```

this is really not a good solution, i wander if there is any better way to solve it